# How to fetch and store data from other table to user table. Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

***Form***

```
{!! Form::select('grade_level[]', $grade_level,[], array('class' => 'form-control','multiple')) !!}
```

***Controller***

*Here is my create function that will return the a view and the list of roles and grade level for users*

```
public function create()
{

$grade_level = GradeLevel::pluck('grade_level','id')->all(); 
$roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->all();
return view('users.create',compact('roles','grade_level'));
}
```

*Here is the store function. and I have encounter a problem MySql Error: 1364 Field 'grade_level_id' doesn't have default value*

```
public function store(Request $request)
{     
$this->validate($request, [
   
    'f_name' => 'required',
    'm_name' => 'required',
    'l_name' => 'required',
    'sex' => 'required',
    'id_number' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    // 'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'username' => 'required|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|same:confirm-password',
    'grade_level_id' => 'required',
    'roles' => 'required'  
]);

$input = $request->all();
$input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
$user = User::create($input);
$user->grade_level_id = $request->grade_level;
$user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));

return redirect()->route('users.index')
                ->with('success','User created successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `User::create()` method to add new user, you'd need to add `grade_level_id` to the `fillable` property or your `User` model.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'grade_level_id'
];
```

Find More about it here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

Either add **'grade_level_id'** to the $fillable of your **user model**,

or

inside your migration, you can add the `->nullable();` extension to the **grade_level_id** field declaration

Comment: It works with ->nullable(); but What if I want to Match the Value of the Parent Key. I mean If I Create a Grade Level with an ID of 2 Then I will choose that specific Grade level for the user then the FK which is the grade_level_id should be 2. By the way Thank you for the response